# OasisR- RStudio Duncan index

Tags: r

I´m very very new at R and Rstudio and not great with programming and stats. I need to calculate a dissimilarity index, and I´m trying to use OasisR package. The function DIDuncan(x) computes an idex for every population group, but is does it in general for the entire data.frame. A need a calculation for each observation and each population gorup. According to:

```r
# https://github.com/cran/OasisR/blob/419f40ff60eb1756a2b8ed0960c5c9e8cb90368d/R/SegFunctions.R
ISDuncan <- function(x) {
  x <- segdataclean(as.matrix(x))$x
  result <- vector(length = ncol(x))
  for (i in 1:ncol(x))
    result[i] <- 0.5 * sum(abs((x[,i]/sum(x[,i])) - ((rowSums(x)-x[,i])/sum((rowSums(x)-x[,i])))))
  return(round(result, 4))
}
```

### Can anyone help me? Thanks!!!
Jor

Thanks SOOOO much! results look good, but it works for the firts observarion? how can I get a matrix or data frame with every observation I have in the data.frame? I'm planning doing this for a large number of observarions
Anyway this is VERY helpfull!!!

Comment: Can you provide sample data and the expected output given that sample data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your interest and help, I'm very lost. I have an Excel sheet where every row is a district of a province. And I want to know ISDuncan value for the social groups in each district A, B and C

[data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8pvn.png)

What I hope is to get is a matrix where the rows represent the district and the columns the social groups, and every district has its own ISDuncan values. Now I'm trying with a small dataset, but I would do this analysis for a large amount of spatial units. Thanks!

Comment: You should leave comment or update your question. Do not post answers for communication purposes.